# JQuery Alerts not centering vertically

Tags: jquery, plugins, alerts

I am using an old jquery plugin for a alert message replacement. The issue I have, is the alerts are popup toward the top of the screen instead of floating to the center. I have tried to modify the CSS to include

```
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```

to no avail.

I would like to modify this jquery function, so it will auto center vertically and horizontally no mater the height or width of the page. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jecker/y5t9d6sL/) giving an example of the issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by changing the positioning from absolute to fixed. Here is a jSFiddle with the changes [Working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sftecbaf/)

```
// jQuery Alert Dialogs Plugin
//
// Version 1.1
//
// Cory S.N. LaViska
// A Beautiful Site (http://abeautifulsite.net/)
// 14 May 2009
//
// Website: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/
//
// Usage:
//      jAlert( message, [title, callback] )
//      jConfirm( message, [title, callback] )
//      jPrompt( message, [value, title, callback] )
// 
// History:
//
//      1.00 - Released (29 December 2008)
//
//      1.01 - Fixed bug where unbinding would destroy all resize events
//
// License:
// 
// This plugin is dual-licensed under the GNU General Public License and the MIT License and
// is copyright 2008 A Beautiful Site, LLC.
//
(function($) {

$.alerts = {

    // These properties can be read/written by accessing $.alerts.propertyName from your scripts at any time

    verticalOffset: -175,                // vertical offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels
    horizontalOffset: 0,                // horizontal offset of the dialog from center screen, in pixels/
    repositionOnResize: true,           // re-centers the dialog on window resize
    overlayOpacity: .01,                // transparency level of overlay
    overlayColor: '#FFF',               // base color of overlay
    draggable: true,                    // make the dialogs draggable (requires UI Draggables plugin)
    okButton: '&nbsp;OK&nbsp;',         // text for the OK button
    cancelButton: '&nbsp;Cancel&nbsp;', // text for the Cancel button
    dialogClass: null,                  // if specified, this class will be applied to all dialogs

    // Public methods

    alert: function(message, title, fieldFocus) {
        if( title == null ) title = 'Alert';
        $.alerts._show(title, message, null, 'alert', fieldFocus);
    },

    confirm: function(message, title) {
        if( title == null ) title = 'Confirm';
        $.alerts._show(title, message, null, 'confirm');
    },

    prompt: function(message, value, title) {
        if( title == null ) title = 'Prompt';
        $.alerts._show(title, message, value, 'prompt');
    },

    // Private methods

    _show: function(title, msg, value, type, field) {
        fieldFocus = '[name="' + field + '"]'; 
        $.alerts._hide();
        $.alerts._overlay('show');

        $("BODY").append(
          '<div id="popup_container">' +
            '<h1 id="popup_title"></h1>' +
            '<div id="popup_content">' +
              '<div id="popup_message"></div>' +
            '</div>' +
          '</div>');

        if( $.alerts.dialogClass ) $("#popup_container").addClass($.alerts.dialogClass);

        // IE6 Fix
        var pos = 'fixed';
        //var pos = 'absolute'; 
        var rel = 'relative'; 

        $("#popup_container").css({
            position: pos,
            zIndex: 99999,
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0
        });

        $("#popup_title").text(title);
        $("#popup_content").addClass(type);
        $("#popup_message").text(msg);
        $("#popup_message").html( $("#popup_message").text().replace(/\n/g, '<br />') );

        $("#popup_container").css({
            minWidth: $("#popup_container").outerWidth(),
            maxWidth: $("#popup_container").outerWidth()
        });

        $.alerts._reposition();
        $.alerts._maintainPosition(true);

        switch( type ) {
            case 'alert':
                $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /></div>');
                $("#popup_container").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    $(fieldFocus).focus();
                });
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                    $(fieldFocus).focus();
                });
                $("#popup_ok").focus().keypress( function(e) {
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                });
            break;
            case 'confirm':
                $("#popup_message").after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.cancelButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                });
                $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                });
                $("#popup_ok").focus();
                $("#popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                    if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
                });
            break;
            case 'prompt':
                $("#popup_message").append('<br /><input type="text" size="30" id="popup_prompt" />').after('<div id="popup_panel"><input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.okButton + '" id="popup_ok" /> <input type="button" value="' + $.alerts.cancelButton + '" id="popup_cancel" /></div>');
                $("#popup_prompt").width( $("#popup_message").width() );
                $("#popup_ok").click( function() {
                    var val = $("#popup_prompt").val();
                    $.alerts._hide();
                });
                $("#popup_cancel").click( function() {
                    $.alerts._hide();
                });
                $("#popup_prompt, #popup_ok, #popup_cancel").keypress( function(e) {
                    if( e.keyCode == 13 ) $("#popup_ok").trigger('click');
                    if( e.keyCode == 27 ) $("#popup_cancel").trigger('click');
                });
                if( value ) $("#popup_prompt").val(value);
                $("#popup_prompt").focus().select();
            break;
        }

        // Make draggable
        if( $.alerts.draggable ) {
            try {
                $("#popup_container").draggable({ handle: $("#popup_title") });
                $("#popup_title").css({ cursor: 'move' });
            } catch(e) { /* requires jQuery UI draggables */ }
        }
    },

    _hide: function() {
        $("#popup_container").remove();
        $.alerts._overlay('hide');
        $.alerts._maintainPosition(false);
    },

    _overlay: function(status) {
        switch( status ) {
            case 'show':
                $.alerts._overlay('hide');
                $("BODY").append('<div id="popup_overlay"></div>');
                $("#popup_overlay").css({
                    position: 'fixed',
                    zIndex: 99998,
                    top: '0px',
                    left: '0px',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: $(document).height(),
                    background: $.alerts.overlayColor,
                    opacity: $.alerts.overlayOpacity
                });
            break;
            case 'hide':
                $("#popup_overlay").remove();
            break;
        }
    },

    _reposition: function() {
        var top = (($(window).height() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerHeight() / 2)) + $.alerts.verticalOffset;
        var left = (($(window).width() / 2) - ($("#popup_container").outerWidth() / 2)) + $.alerts.horizontalOffset;
        if( top < 0 ) top = 0;
        if( left < 0 ) left = 0;


        $("#popup_container").css({
            top: top + 'px',
            left: left + 'px'
        });
        $("#popup_overlay").height( $(document).height() );
    },

    _maintainPosition: function(status) {
        if( $.alerts.repositionOnResize ) {
            switch(status) {
                case true:
                    $(window).bind('resize', $.alerts._reposition);
                break;
                case false:
                    $(window).unbind('resize', $.alerts._reposition);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

// Shortuct functions
jAlert = function(message, title, fieldFocus) {
    $.alerts.alert(message, title, fieldFocus);
}

jConfirm = function(message, title) {
    $.alerts.confirm(message, title);
};

jPrompt = function(message, value, title) {
    $.alerts.prompt(message, value, title);
};

})(jQuery);

$("#test").on('click', function() {
jAlert("This is a test", 'Error', 'test');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave a

height:200px;

to #popup_container

and in jquery function make

verticalOffset: 0,

try it please and say the result.

**EDIT:**

Here is [my fiddle][1]

I just edited
verticalOffset: 0

in jquery.  Thats all.

```
    [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/oneNiceFriend/ms8kwdj7/1/
```

Comment: Nope no change. I made the changes you suggested, and the vertical position is still the same.

Comment: I am trying to get it to float vertically center.

Comment: That is much better. The ultimate solution would have the alert box appearing in the center of the screen and maintaining the center position even when the user scrolls up or down.

Comment: @Jecker What do you mean by centre of the screen? Do you mean of the current window? Or the whole document and it's position is fixed in the whole screen? Or Do you want it to be in the centre of window and stay there even if they scroll?

Comment: I want it to be in the centre of window and stay there even if they scroll or disable scrolling.